# Performance difference between Runspace and Job

Tags: multithreading, powershell

I built a file processor script to convert some files to json. It works but not fast enough, so I am multithreading it. I prefer to use runspace pools since you can specify a max thread limit and it will run that many threads at a time and add new work as it completes other threads, spiffy. But I've found that if I have, say, 6 threads of work to complete, using runspaces takes ~50 minutes and keeps my computer at 40% CPU, while just using Start-Job for each piece of work pegs my computer at 100% CPU, and the work completes in 15 minutes. Am I misconfiguring the runspacepool in some way? Here are simplified examples of each

```
### Using Start-Job ###

$files = C:\temp | Get-Childitem -filter '*.xel' # returns 6 items

foreach ($file in $files) {

    #simplified
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock { C:\temp\FileProcessor.ps1 -filepath $using:file.fullname }

}




### Using Runspace Pool ###

$files = C:\temp | Get-Childitem -filter '*.xel' # returns 6 items

$Code = {
    param ($filepath)

    #simplified
    C:\temp\FileProcessor.ps1 -filepath $filepath

}

$rsPool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1,100)
$rsPool.Open()

$threads = @()

foreach ($file in $files) {

        $PSinstance = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($Code).AddArgument($file.FullName)
        $PSinstance.RunspacePool = $rsPool
        $threads += $PSinstance.BeginInvoke()    

}

while ($threads.IsCompleted -contains $False) {}

$rsPool.Dispose()
```

I may also be misunderstanding runspaces compared to jobs, any help is welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jobs use multiple processes...